# Index of dictionary to another dictionary

Tags: python

hey I have been trying to get this value from one dictionary and use it as a key with another dictionary. and I get `keyError`

```
userID = some input lets say 364853

BALANCE = {540997: 10500, 266732: 50000}

ACCOUNTS = {364853: 540997, 266732: 540922}
```

and I'm trying to print:

```
print(ACCOUNTS[BALANCE[userId]])
```

and i get keyError( 364853 )

Comment: UserID is in ACCOUNTS dict, you are looking it in BALANCE dict

Comment: you want to look up the balance dict using the value from the accounts dict `BALANCE[ACCOUNTS[userId]]`

Comment: print (BALANCE[ACCOUNTS[userId]])
KeyError: '364853'

Comment: You are passing the accunt ID as a string, but your dict has the account ids as ints. you need to convert it to an int then `BALANCE[ACCOUNTS[int(userId)]]`

Answer (score 2):

You have your references backwards.  Let's do this in order.  You have a userID; you need to get the account number.  First, if this is the straight user input -- a string, rather than the `int` you show in your code and error message -- then you must convert it.  Then you look it up in ACCOUNTS:

```
acct_no = ACCOUNTS[int(userID)]
```

Now, you use the account number to get the balance:

```
user_bal = BALANCE[acct_no]
```

In this statement, using simple algebraic substitution:

```
user_bal = BALANCE[ACCOUNTS[userID]]
```

See how that works?  In English, this reads as "I want the balance of the account of the userID".

Comment: this is weird im doing the same thing it seems like it cant find the key in ACCOUNT dict

Comment: Look again: this is *not* the statement you posted.  You're trying to look up the key in the BALANCE dict.

Comment: this is what iv been trying to do print (BALANCE[ACCOUNTS[userId]]) , in what iv posted i made type mistake

Comment: your userid is a string but your keys are ints, they are not the same, so the code is corret the string your looking up as a key in the dict isnt there. this is why its important to post a minimum example of your problem and not just say `userId = #some value 12345`, cause clearly its  a string you rprobably take from input

Comment: Yes -- if your userID is a string, you have another correction to make in your post.

Comment: @ChrisDoyle: if the input were a string, that would show in the error message.

Comment: In the comments on the question the user shows `print (BALANCE[ACCOUNTS[userId]]) KeyError: '364853'`. here it clear the key being looked up is a string

Comment: I see -- the question itself is wrong ... in more than one respect.
In any case, the two observations should fix OP's problems.

Comment: Yeah your answer is correct, but the reason it doesnt work for the user is the failed to mention the userId is a string and all the keys are ints